# CMWImpt.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not was not found. This file cannot be registered'

Tags: dll, vb6

I have a vb6 project, and when i tried to run the source code I got an error which points to the CMWImpt.dll.

I tried to put the dll in the System32, sysWow64, and project folder, and registered it. But this is the error:
CMWImpt.dll  was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not was not found. This file cannot be registered'

anyone who encountered this before?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message?

Not all dlls are registerable. Only COM dlls have registration. And they are usually but not always in the dll (sometimes in another dll).

Error messages that mention dll names are not COM errors mostly. COM errors are of the type "Cannot create activex object", unless correctly registered and the file deleted.

So your file is either corrupted or not a COM dll.

The WinAPI uses dynamic linking. DLL stands for Dynamic Link Library, COM dlls have 4 or so standard dynamic functions to controll COM like DLLRegisterServer.

So you need to provide more detailed info on the problem.